# Add repeated elements of array indexed by another array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-indexing

I have a relatively simple problem that I cannot solve without using loops. It is difficult for me to figure out the correct title for this problem.
Lets say we have two numpy arrays:

```
array_1 = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
                    [3, 3, 3],
                    [3, 3, 4],
                    [3, 6, 2]])

array_2 = np.array([[0, 0, 0], 
                    [1, 1, 1],
                    [2, 2, 2],
                    [3, 3, 3],
                    [4, 4, 4],
                    [5, 5, 5],
                    [6, 6, 6]])
```

`array_1` represents indices of the rows in `array_2` that we want to `sum`. So for example, `4`th row in `result` array should contain summed all rows in `array_2` that have same row indices as all `3`s in array_1.

It is much easier to understand it in the code:

```
result = np.empty(array_2.shape)

for i in range(array_1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(array_1.shape[1]):
        index = array_1[i, j]
        result[index] = result[index] + array_2[i]
```

Result should be:

```
[[ 0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0]
 [ 3  3  3]
 [10 10 10]
 [ 2  2  2]
 [ 0  0  0]
 [ 3  3  3]]
```

I tried to use `np.einsum` but I need to use both elements in array as indices and also its rows as indices so I'm not sure if `np.einsum` is the best path here.

This is the problem I have in graphics. `array_1` represent indices of vertices for triangles and `array_2` represents normals where index of a row corresponds to the index of the vertex

Comment: Problem is clear, but I am curious: why would you want to solve this without loops?

Comment: This is the problem I have in graphics so `array_1` and `array_2` can be massive and this can get extremely slow. But what bugs me the most with this problem is that there are just two simple for loops and I can't port them to numpy. It is making my brain boil for 3rd day

Comment: "and I can't port them to numpy.". Why do you want to do this? Do you want to speed up the algorithm? What is it you are trying to achieve at the end of the day?

Comment: Yes. I want to speed it up

Comment: Shouldn't the outupt have the same size as `array1`, not `array2`?

Comment: @sarema. If you vectorize this, it will run 10-100x faster

Comment: I know that. I just wanted to make sure this is actually his goal

Comment: Just to make sure I'm reading it right, first row of output is `array2[0] + array2[1] + array2[2]`, since `array1[0]` is `[0, 1, 2]`?

Comment: No first row is summed all rows that have same indices as `0`s in `array_1`, so first row should be `[0, 0, 0]`, second row should be also `[0, 0, 0]`, third row `[3, 3, 3]`, fourth `[10, 10, 10]`... Fourth is `[10, 10, 10]` because `3` happens the most

Comment: OK. So the output is actually `(array_1.max() + 1, array_2.shape[1])` in size, since the shape of `array_2` has nothing to do with it. You never select a row past the fourth, since `array_1` only has four rows. So for example, `result[6] == [3, 3, 3]` because the only `6` is in row `3`.

Comment: No. Output array has to have the same size as the `array_2`, that's why I put or purpose the max value to be 6 in `array_1`. Output array should have 7 rows, same as `array_2`

Comment: Since `i` is used in `array_2[i]` in the inner loop, and `i` goes from 0 to 3 (inclusive), then only the first four rows of `array_2` are actually used in the `result` array. Is this correct?

Comment: Get the looped version working correctly and show the results.  Then we can talk about doing the same thing with the full power of numpy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time you're adding something from a repeated index, normal ufuncs like [`np.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html) don't work out of the box because they only process a repeated fancy index once. Instead, you have to use the unbuffered version, which is [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html#numpy.ufunc.at).

Here, you have a pair of indices: the row in `array_1` is the row index into `array_2`, and the element of `array_1` is the row index into the output.

First, construct the indices explicitly as [fancy indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing). This will make it much simpler to use them:

```
output_row = array_1.ravel()
input_row = np.repeat(np.arange(array_1.shape[0]), array_1.shape[1]).ravel()
```

You can apply `input_row` directly to `array_2`, but you need `add.at` to use `output_row`:

```
output = np.zeros_like(array_2)
np.add.at(output, output_row, array_2[input_row])
```

You really only use the first four rows of `array_2`, so it could be truncated to

```
array_2 = array2[:array_1.shape[0]]
```

In that case, you would want to initialize the output as:

```
output = np.zeros_like(array_2, shape=(output_row.max() + 1, array2.shape[1]))
```

Comment: That's not correct. The shape of the result is `(4, 3)`, which is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @sarema. See update. I have the same answer as OP now.

Comment: Wow. I will have to reread this answer a couple of times to fully understand it. Thank You!. Anyway, I have no idea what title to put on this question. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I see. Impressive!

Comment: @NemanjaStojanovic. I've found fancy indexing to be much more counterintuitive than `np.ufunc.at`. All it does is allow you to do `output[output_row] += array_2[input_row]` correctly. I would recommend two things: first forget that the arrays are 2D and work with a 1D example, then read the docs on fancy indexing: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing